# How do I play this section from wedding march?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, sheet-music, keyboard

I have been struggling with this for so long, and I cant find any answers. Plz tell me how do I play it? I would be thankful if anyone could explain what that chord below  G means and what Tr means. Plz also write the chord, thank you!

Edit - This is a keyboard solo piece from Trinity London grade 7 - electronic keyboard book! Also as to specify my question more, I dont understand how am I supposed to play the notes below G chord, like F , D together and then G? ANd if so in how many beats? I also tried searching on youtube but I couldnt find any answers. I also have a link to a reference video on youtube.

I am sorry if I seem silly, but I am self taught so I really have no idea *sweat smile*

[The song played by some other youtuber-](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENDnE_WqV0A)

[image]
[image: "Wedding March" measure 7]

Comment: What is unclear about the G chord?

Comment: Did you 'Youtube' it, and watch how others do it?

Comment: Further to @Aaron's comment: is this an arrangement for piano solo? (If so, where's the bass line?) Or is it piano duet or piano + other instrument(s)? If so, even though all the notes are on the top stave, your left hand could play some of the lower notes, seeing as it has nothing else to do.

Comment: Although I've voted to reopen this question, it is likely a duplicate. I have not yet found the identical question, however.

Comment: A duplicate? Hmm, I don't think so. I searched if people were having trouble with this piece like me, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Glad to see that OP made the effort to see whether their question was a duplicate, but unfortunately they mean it's possibly a duplicate in that the underlying questions about understanding that type of chord voicing and the meaning of "tr" in sheet music have probably been asked here before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Tr' means 'trill'. Play the note and the diatonic note above it alternately. As in DCDCDCDCD, quite fast, while the lower two notes are held only for the short quaver shown.  I'd be playing it with two hands (left hand is doing nothing else), so E and G l.h., trill,r.h., whichever fingers you are better with - the suggestion here is 5434, but there are other combinations.

The end of the trill is BC, up to D - that chord being basically G7, which can all be played easily with r.h.

EDIT: I've just realised where the question is coming from! Although the heads are on either side of the stem (F and D on left, G on right), all three are played at the same time - it's the only way the F and G can be written! Were all the dots on the same side, it'd look like an indecipherable blob.

Comment: Trill starts on D and ends on C.

Comment: @Aaron - thanks, hence the 54 fingering. But the 34 after only makes sense with DCBC notes, doesn't it? I rarely trill these days, leave that up to budgies, but I tend to start with the lower note if I have to. Edited so far.

Comment: Hmm. I see now I misread the fingering initially. I saw 5343, which is common. I agree that 34 only makes sense at the end of the trill, except then the given fingering for the following chord doesn't work. Musescore strikes again, perhaps? Leaving comment for OP....

Answer (score 3):

The chord below `G` is `G7` but without the 3rd (`B`) in it.  It hints at the `B` in the notes running up to it (`B-C`).

`Tr` is short for `Trill` the act of playing 2 notes repeatedly and quickly.  You're struggling because it calls for the 2 weakest fingers to pull off this particular trill (4,5).  Play it slowly and your fingers will eventually obey you :-)

Comment: Or use both hands, so the trill can be done with sensible fingers...